# How do you know RStudio is running?

Tags: r

I have a quick, simple question -- how do you know `R` is running and it's not stopped?

I am running an optimizer from the `GA` package and I assumed that the computational time would be enormous, but as I pushed the `GA` loop, `R` just seems like it's stopped, but no returning error though.

As I open the task manager, I can see that it's using around 0% of CPU. The first column being the CPU and the second the storage.

[image: First column the CPU and second the storage]

How do I know the process is still running and not freezed?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you show what you see in your task manager? What is GA?

Comment: @Llopis thanks for the reply! I added a screenshot of the task manager. GA is just a function being pushed into R.

Comment: So, where is R process? How do you push a function into R?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

RStudio spawns processes called "RStudio R session" that actually do the work. You should be able to find them in your task manager in the 'Background processes section'. Here's an example I generated after running `while (TRUE) {x <- 2 + 1}` which will ask R to do something pointless forever.

[image: Task manager snip]

Comment: I only find the RStudio R Session in the Applications section (not background processes section), but I suppose that, as long as I see that the RStudio R Session is using CPU, it means that the processing is still going  on (NOT freezed), correct? I know the process I am running is time consuming, but it has been quite a few days now, so I cant help wondering about it. Thanks

Comment: Is there a way to check the child processes?